# Flash doesn't cache PHP anymore?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, caching

I am loading this PHP file from my server:

```
<?php
echo date('z Y H:i:s');
?>
```

and I always get the current time rather than an old, cached one. I am loading it normally, without any `"?"+Math.random()` at the end of its address.

Can anyone confirm that Flash intentionally no longer caches .php files? Or do I get something wrong?

***Edit:***

I don't know if this clarifies things or perplexes them more, but here is my PHP loading class:

```
package fanlib.utils
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

public class QuickLoad
{
    static private const DONT_GC:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    private var funcLoaded:Function;

    public function QuickLoad(file:String, funcLoaded:Function, format:String = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT, skipCache:Boolean = false)
    {
        DONT_GC[this] = this;

        this.funcLoaded = funcLoaded;
        const loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = format;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);

        const request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);

        if (skipCache) {
            const header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        //  request.data = new URLVariables("cache=no+cache");
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            request.requestHeaders.push(header);
        }

        loader.load(request);
    }

    private function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
        var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);
        funcLoaded(loader.data);
        delete DONT_GC[this]; // get me now
        funcLoaded = null;
    }

    private function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace(this, e.text);
    }
}
}
```

I get the same uncached result whether I am setting `skipCache` to either true or false.

Comment: What does the HTTP Response Header direct the Browser to do about caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has nothing to do with the cached HTML.  It is the HTTP Response Header (e.g. max-age, pragma, expiration, ETag) and the method used to load the page (e.g. POST Requests do not cache, Refresh may override cache)

Have you tried:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sun, 1 Mar 2015 00:00:00 GMT");  
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");`
```

Or if you could use a POST link.
Rather than `<a href="page.php">>Link Text</a>`

```
<form action="page.php" method="post"><button>Link Text</button></form>
```

Comment: I may have not made myself clear, but I DON'T want to restore cached info, if I did yes, the 2 methods you propose would be just find. I only need to know if I need to use dubious methods (like ?random()) to get uncached results, or if I can do it straightforward

Comment: This is why, you said:  "I always get the current time rather than an old, cached one."  so I assumed you wanted the other rather than the one you "always" get.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's not what I *wanted*, rather what I *expected* :-) BTW, your nickname is greatly matched to this misunderstanding :-)))